# Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=27025

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

This link is stored in my Available Software Sites.

However when I go to check for Software Updates, I get this error (unless I disable it).

When I try to reload it from the Available Software Sites it fails.

I use Android Developer Tools. Is this something I need? Can anyone provide me a valid link?